# Returning json into ajax from php file

Tags: php, ajax, json

Seems to be everything ok, but I can't access the data inside the javascript. I know its something easy and have a lot of tutos everywhere, but I'm a little confused. Someone can help me?

Here is the three pieces of code, really simple:

foo.js

```
$.ajax({ 

    data: {'termo': termo},
    url: 'http://localhost/tarefa66/sysvendas/getFestas.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#resultado').text(JSON.parse(data)[0]);
    }


});
```

getFestas.php

```
    echo json_encode(getFestas($_GET['termo']));
```

dao.php

```
    $getFestas = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM festa f WHERE f.nome LIKE '%" . $termo . "%'");

    return $getFestas->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Output on network tab (Firefox) https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfKuS.png

============================================================

Problem solved.
1. The complete method don't receive 'data', 'success' do.

The php return is something like '[{"prop": 'value'}]', so doing this 'JSON.parse(data)[0]'
I was just accessing the Object inside the array - that can't be printed.

So the right use is: `obj = JSON.parse(data)[0];` and after access like `obj['prop']`.

Comment: Can you share your code here instead of linking externally?

Comment: @scrowler, yes. Sorry, I had a problem before but now it's working.

Comment: Look at the `$.ajax()` docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ You want `success: function(data) {...}` not `complete: function(data) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to set text to a javascript object instead of a string.  try

```
    complete: function(data) {
        $('#resultado').text(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)[0]));
    }
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the data type to json explicitly.  Then you can access data as a javascript object without parsing it yourself.

```
$.ajax({ 

    data: {'termo': termo},
    url: 'http://localhost/tarefa66/sysvendas/getFestas.php',
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(data) {
        $('#resultado').text(data[0]);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing `}` from complete function..

```
$.ajax({ 

    data: {'termo': termo},
    url: 'http://localhost/tarefa66/sysvendas/getFestas.php',
    complete: function(data) {
      $('#resultado').text(JSON.parse(data)[0]);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thx, @skrilled, but it's still not working. This was a bad Ctrl+C/V.